# Target font size=2 with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to use an markup code of a different company and they use pretty awkward markup code. I can't edit the HTML only the CSS is up to me. Now the markup code looks like that:

```
<p>
  <font size="2">Headline</font>
  <font size"1">Paragraph text</font>
</p>
```

I'd like to style the color and other things to these 2 elements differently but I have no clue on how to target them within CSS. Something like that?

```
font[size=2] {
  color: red;
}

font[size=1] {
  green;
}
```

Comment: did you try `font[size="1"]` as CSS selector?

Comment: Nope. These things are within a form and in there within the thankyou-message. Everytime I testride it, I trigger the whole thankyou process on my clients-side and I'd like to keep that as little as possible (as I already did it 345 times) - so n real debugging there. My suggestion would be it was font[size=1]{
green;
} but I have no real clue there

Comment: I think `<font>` has been deprecated ages ago.

Comment: I mean for the CSS selector you need `"` surrounding the attributes value. In your question you used `font[size=1]` but with `font[size="1"]` it should work

Comment: @Terry: I'd assume that's why the asker called the markup they're working with "pretty awkward".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
font[size="2"] {
  color: red;
}

font[size="1"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <font size="2">Headline</font>
  <font size="1">Paragraph text</font>
</p>
```

Comment: And if that wasn't specific enough, it was? p font[size="2"]{color:red; }

Answer (score 2):

In attribute and value selector, value should be in string `font[size="1"]`

```css
font[size="2"] {
  color: red;
}

font[size="1"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <font size="2">Headline</font>
  <font size="1">Paragraph text</font>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `font[size=1]` but with **quotation marks** `font[size="1"]`